# Limiting length of Windows RDP Session

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I'm currently trying to limit the length of a Windows RDP session to about 1 min 30 seconds. I've set the `MaxConnectionTime` registry key at `HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services\` to 90000 (90 seconds). Unfortunately, when this time limit is reached, an error message like the one in the screenshot pops up. It says

> Logon timer expired:
>   Session has now exceeded its time limit, Logoff will start in 2 minutes.

[image: Error Message]

I would like to make this 90 second limit a hard cap, instead of basically allowing it to be 3 min and 30 seconds. Does anyone know which combination of registry keys I would need to modify in order to make this happen?